# Why does the limit of adjacent numbers in the n-bonacci sequence approach 2 as n goes to infinity?

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

> (1, 1.0)
> (2, 1.618033988749895)
> (3, 1.8392867552141612)
> (4, 1.9275619754829254)
> (5, 1.9659482366454852)
> (6, 1.9835828434243263)
> (7, 1.991964196605035)
> (8, 1.9960311797354147)
> (9, 1.9980294702622867)
> (10, 1.9990186327101012)
> (11, 1.9995104019782854)
> (12, 1.9997555009373176)
> (13, 1.9998778327115456)
> (14, 1.9999389387495947)
> (15, 1.9999694754345032)
> (16, 1.9999847393479442)
> (17, 1.9999923701106546)
> (18, 1.9999961851717603)
> (19, 1.9999980926168055)
> (20, 1.9999990463165884)
> (21, 1.9999995231604544)
> (22, 1.9999997615807956)
> (23, 1.999999880790547)
> (24, 1.9999999403953126)
> (25, 1.9999999701976665)
> (26, 1.999999985098836)
> (27, 1.9999999925494187)
> (28, 1.9999999962747095)
> (29, 1.9999999981373549)
> (30, 1.9999999990686774)
> (31, 1.9999999995343387)
> (32, 1.9999999997671694)
> (33, 1.9999999998835847)
> (34, 1.9999999999417923)
> (35, 1.9999999999708962)
> (36, 1.999999999985448)
> (37, 1.999999999992724)
> (38, 1.999999999996362)
> (39, 1.999999999998181)
> (40, 1.9999999999990905)
> (41, 1.9999999999995453)
> (42, 1.9999999999997726)
> (43, 1.9999999999998863)
> (44, 1.9999999999999432)
> (45, 1.9999999999999716)
> (46, 1.9999999999999858)
> (47, 1.999999999999993)
> (48, 1.9999999999999964)
> (49, 1.9999999999999982)

I ran this on a computer. The first member of each of the above ordered pairs represents the number of initial elements in the sequence, i.e., $n$. For example, when $n = 2$,

Initial sequence = ${1, 1}$

We add the last $n$ terms of the sequence to produce the next term.

${1, 1, 2} \\ {1, 1, 2, 3} \\ {1, 1, 2, 3, 5}, etc.$

When $n = 3$

${1, 1, 1} \\ {1, 1, 1, 3} \\ {1, 1, 1, 3, 5} \\ {1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 9}, etc.$

The ratio of adjacent numbers in these sequences all approach a certain limit. The limits for each $n$ from 1 to 49 are quoted above. It is well known that the ratio of adjacent terms in the 2-bonacci (Fibonacci) sequence tends to $\phi = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$.

It doesn't approach two itself. Each n-bonacci sequence has an adjacent-term-ratio limiting to some value less than two. For instance, I ran 49-bonacci up to thousand and then ten thousand terms and the ratio of the last two numbers was 1.9999999999999982 in both cases (low-res computer).  But as the value $n$ gets bigger, the *limit* itself gets closer and closer to two. For instance, limit of 25-bonacci is 1.9999999701976665, whereas that of 30-bonacci is 1.9999999990686774.

Why is it so?

Comment: The exact limit ratio is the root of $x^{n + 1} - 2 x ^ n + 1$ (with similar methods than the Fibonnaci case) which gets closer to 2 when n gets bigger

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers#Higher_orders